# Bifurcation Diagram not plotting / Plot just not showing up

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, ipython

My homework assignment has me writing a code that models figures in classical mechanics by Taylor textbook. Figures [image: 12.40] and [image: 12.41] if anyone is interested to know.

I was able to reproduce one of them which is the code below (which might be good reference for the code I'm ACTUALLY having issues with):

```
import nympy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# We need to calculate the first fixed point
r1=np.array(np.arange(0,4,0.09))
x1 = np.zeros((len(r1),1))

# Now calculating the second fixed point
r2=np.array(np.arange(1,4,0.1))
x2 = (r2 -1)/r2

# Now finding when the fixed points split up again
r3=np.array(np.arange(3,4,0.1))
y1 = (((r3**2 - 2*r3 - 3)**0.5) + 1 + r3)/(2*r3)
y2 = ((-(r3**2 - 2*r3 - 3)**0.5) + 1 + r3)/(2*r3)

# Now finding the experimental values for 1/2 of a split
x3 = []
for r in np.arange(0,4,0.09):
    x = 0.666
    for i in range(100):
       x = (r**2) * x * (1.0 -x) - (r**3) * (x**2)*((1-x)**2)
    x3.append(x)

# Doing the same as above second 1/2
x4 = []
for r in np.arange(0,4,0.09):
    x = 0.8
    for i in range(100):
       x = (r**2) * x * (1.0 -x) - (r**3) * (x**2)*((1-x)**2)
    x4.append(x)

plt.plot(r1,x3,'bo', label='Experimental')
plt.plot(r1,x4,'bo')
plt.plot(r3,y2,'k-')
plt.plot(r3,y1,'k-')
plt.plot(r1,x1,'k-', label='Theoretical')
plt.plot(r2,x2,'k-')
plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.show()
```

And here's the code for the second image that doesn't seem to working. And I'm not sure why. Any help would be appreciated. The figure just doesn't plot, and I'm not sure why.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for r in n.arange(2.8,4,0.01):
    x = 0.5
    for i in range(150):
        x = r*x*(1-x)
        if i >= 125:
            plt.plot(r,x,'k')
plt.xlim (2.8,4)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome so stack overflow. Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, please paste your code instead of inserting images. There's a `{}` button in the post that indents everything by four spaces and it will display as code

Comment: Are You using IPython notebook?

Answer (score 0):

There's a good reason your code isn't working.

You're calling `plt.plot` repeatedly with scalar values, when an array is expected for x and y: it's pretty hard to plot a line with only **one** point.
Try this, you'll see you'll get an empty plot:

```
plt.plot(0,1)
plt.show();
```

I have no idea if this is what you're looking for ultimately, but here's a working version you can at least use for a starting point. Note that I changed the loop on i: instead of doing `i in range(150)` followed by `if i >=125`, better just do `i in range(125,150)`, you'll avoid needless iterations:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
r1 = []
x1 = []
for r in np.arange(2.8,4,0.01):
    x=0.5
    # Instead of range(150) then checking if i >= 125...
    for i in range(125,150):
        x = r*x*(1-x)
        r1.append(r)
        x1.append(x)

ax.plot(r1,x1,'k')
plt.show()
```

[image: Result graph]

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this one year old post and realized that there is a simple answer to the problem reported by the OP.

The missing bit was the **marker** argument.

Replace `plot(r,x,'k')` with `plot(r,x,'.',color='k')` and suddenly the bifurcation plot is revealed.

[image: Bifurcation for logistic regression]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
for r in n.arange(2.8,4,0.01):
    x = 0.5
    for i in range(150):
        x = r*x*(1-x)
        if i >= 125:
            plt.plot(r,x,'.',color='black',markersize=2)
plt.xlim (2.8,4)
plt.show()
```

This code is fine, though rather inefficient. It is much faster to call `plot()` only once.

```
plt.figure()
def mark(r,x,diagram,v):
    N,M = np.shape(diagram)
    rmin,rmax = r[0],r[-1]
    for (i,j) in zip(r,x):
        nx = int(j*(M-1))
        nr = int((i-rmin)/(rmax-rmin)*(N-1))
        diagram[nx,nr] = v

r = np.arange(2.8,4,0.01)
diagram = np.zeros((200,200))
x0 = 0.5
x = np.ones_like(r)*x0
for i in range(150):
    x = np.multiply(np.multiply(r,x),(1-x))
    if i >= 125:
        mark(r,x,diagram,1)

plt.imshow(np.flipud(diagram), extent=[r[0],r[-1],0,1],
           aspect=(r[-1]-r[0]),cmap=plt.cm.Greys)
plt.show()
```

[image: Another bifurcation diagram]

The latter code uses

```
CPU times: user 224 ms, sys: 29 µs, total: 224 ms
Wall time: 261 ms
```

While the former less efficient code takes over 30 times longer

```
CPU times: user 8.59 s, sys: 91.7 ms, total: 8.68 s
Wall time: 8.68 s
```